# pdftk merge of small image pdf creates a large overlay

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, pdftk

- FreeBSD-12.3p5
- pdftk 3.3.2_1

I have a pdf file of an 87x87 pixel QRcode created from a png image file.

```
qrencode --output=QR.png IN999999
magick identify QR.png
QR.png PNG 87x87 87x87+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 651B 0.000u 0:00.000
magick convert -transparent white QR.png QR.pdf
pdftk IN999999.pdf stamp QR.pdf output QRIN999999.pdf
```

What this produces is a merged QRIN999999.pdf file with the contents of QR.pdf overlaid and expanded to the full size of the page of IN999999.pdf.  What I need is for the merged image to remain at 87x87.

I cannot seem to discover from the documentation how to do this.  In fact, I do not understand why `pdftk` is expanding the image.  Both QR.png and QR.pdf quite clearly display the image in the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

Pdftk does not have options to choose the scale and positions of overlays, so a solution would be to create a PDF with the same page size as the original, with the image placed in the appropriate position, then use that as the stamp. Imagemagick can do that (e.g. `convert -page A4`).